# How to automate reading files in the folder?

Tags: automation, robotics, rpa, g1ant

I have some folder on my desktop, let's call it FOLDER_X. 
I want to read all the names of files which are in the FOLDER_X. 
Is it possible to do it with G1ANT, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also with usage of snippets, i.e. C#:

```
♥files = ⟦list⟧⊂System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("your path here")⊃
foreach ♥file in ♥files
    dialog ♥file
end
```

If you want to remove the path from ♥file place this line at the beginning of the loop:

```
    text.replace regex ‴^.*\\‴ text ♥file replace ‴‴ result ♥file
```

Comment: whats up with the ♥s? is this shorthand for something?

Comment: Heart sign is used to mark that a name is a variable. Ctrl+4 in G1ANT Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The below script will display all names of files that are in the FOLDER_X.

The `directory` command will retrieve all the directories and files that are in the specified path and create the `♥result` variable containing all the data in a list.

The `foreach` loop will iterate through the found elements which are of G1ANT [path](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Language/Structures/PathStructure.md) structure. There are several indexes that you can use, for example `isfile` and `name` that are useful here.

```
directory path ‴♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\FOLDER_X‴

foreach ♥element in ♥result
    dialog ♥element⟦name⟧ if ⊂♥element⟦isfile⟧⊃
end foreach
```